# Moving Mouse in C# (coordinate units)

Tags: c#, click, mouse, move

I'm trying to make Teamviewer like piece of software for fun, which allows one person to view another person's screen and click and all that. Anyway, I have most all of the socket stuff done, but I don't know how to get the mouse clicks to work correctly. Here is the code I found online for moving the mouse programmatically:

```
  public static class VirtualMouse
{
    // import the necessary API function so .NET can
    // marshall parameters appropriately
    [DllImport("user32.dll")]
    static extern void mouse_event(int dwFlags, int dx, int dy, int dwData, int dwExtraInfo);

    // constants for the mouse_input() API function
    private const int MOUSEEVENTF_MOVE = 0x0001;
    private const int MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTDOWN = 0x0002;
    private const int MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTUP = 0x0004;
    private const int MOUSEEVENTF_RIGHTDOWN = 0x0008;
    private const int MOUSEEVENTF_RIGHTUP = 0x0010;
    private const int MOUSEEVENTF_MIDDLEDOWN = 0x0020;
    private const int MOUSEEVENTF_MIDDLEUP = 0x0040;
    private const int MOUSEEVENTF_ABSOLUTE = 0x8000;


    // simulates movement of the mouse.  parameters specify changes
    // in relative position.  positive values indicate movement
    // right or down
    public static void Move(int xDelta, int yDelta)
    {
        mouse_event(MOUSEEVENTF_MOVE, xDelta, yDelta, 0, 0);
    }


    // simulates movement of the mouse.  parameters specify an
    // absolute location, with the top left corner being the
    // origin
    public static void MoveTo(int x, int y)
    {
        mouse_event(MOUSEEVENTF_ABSOLUTE | MOUSEEVENTF_MOVE, x, y, 0, 0);
    }


    // simulates a click-and-release action of the left mouse
    // button at its current position
    public static void LeftClick()
    {
        mouse_event(MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTDOWN, Control.MousePosition.X, Control.MousePosition.Y, 0, 0);
        mouse_event(MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTUP, Control.MousePosition.X, Control.MousePosition.Y, 0, 0);
    }
}
```

Now I want to move the mouse using the MoveTo method, but it requires crazy high numbers for any movement. Is there anyway I can match coordinates for moving here to the position on screen in pixels? Sorry if this seems like an obvious question, but I've googled for almost an hour and I can't find any discussion of what units are being used for the mouse x and y position, so I can't set up any sort of formula to match clicks on one panel to clicks on the user's screen.

Comment: [`Cursor.Position`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.cursor.position.aspx) looks promising.

Answer (score 7):

From [Microsoft's documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms646260%28v=vs.85%29.aspx):

> If MOUSEEVENTF_ABSOLUTE value is specified, dx and dy contain
>   normalized absolute coordinates between 0 and 65,535. The event
>   procedure maps these coordinates onto the display surface. Coordinate
>   (0,0) maps onto the upper-left corner of the display surface,
>   (65535,65535) maps onto the lower-right corner.

You can use that to convert the input in pixels to the desired value, like this:

```
var inputXinPixels = 200;
var inputYinPixels = 200;
var screenBounds = System.Windows.Forms.Screen.PrimaryScreen.Bounds;
var outputX = inputXinPixels * 65535 / screenBounds.Width;
var outputY = inputYinPixels * 65535 / screenBounds.Height;
MoveTo(outputX, outputY);
```

Please keep in mind that this may not be correct for multiple monitors. Also notice that the documention says:

> This function has been superseded. Use [SendInput](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms646310%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) instead.

**Addendum**: As [pointed by J3soon](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12870535/moving-mouse-in-c-sharp-coordinate-units/12870616?noredirect=1#comment85268201_12870616) the above formula might not be the best. Based on [research done for AutoHokey](https://autohotkey.com/board/topic/9317-mousemove-distorts-coords-near-lefttop-edges-of-screen/) the internal the following code works better:

```
var outputX = (inputXinPixels * 65536 / screenBounds.Width) + 1;
var outputY = (inputYinPixels * 65536 / screenBounds.Height) + 1;
```

See [AutoHotkey source code](https://github.com/Lexikos/AutoHotkey_L/blob/master/source/keyboard_mouse.cpp#L2545) for reference.

---

If I were in your position I would use Cursor.Position. The following code works as expected:

```
System.Windows.Forms.Cursor.Position = new System.Drawing.Point(200, 200);
```

Yes, it places the mouse pointer in the coordinates (200, 200) pixels of the screen [Tested on LinqPad].

**Addendum**: I had a look at what does `System.Windows.Forms.Cursor.Position` use internally - On Mono on Windows at least. It is a call to `SetCursorPos`. No weird coordinate conversion needed.

Comment: `inputXinPixels * 65536 / SCREEN_WIDTH + 1` works better in my case, which is also used in [AutoHotKey](https://github.com/Lexikos/AutoHotkey_L/blob/58842fb2956fe082bc11476316d4590b0e2ee8a8/source/keyboard_mouse.cpp#L2545).