# Calculate normalized coordinates for SendInput() in a multi-monitor environment

Tags: c++, c, windows, winapi, sendinput

I want to send mouse input programmatically to anyone of my connected displays.

I know I can use the [SendInput](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-sendinput) function to do this, but my current approach doesn't work on a multi-display setup.

I am using the following approach:

1. Get pixel coordinates of the point to click, relative to the current screen;
2. Get pixel coordinates of the topleft pixel of the current screen, using [GetMonitorInfoW](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-getmonitorinfow) function with the appropriate HMONITOR handle;
3. Get the pixel coordinates relative to the whole virtual screen: to do this, we sum the coordinates of the current screen margin (topleft pixel) with the coordinates of the point to click;
4. Transform the resulting pixel coordinates into **absolute coordinates (0-65535)**, to be used by the SendInput function;
5. Use the [SendInput](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-sendinput) function with MOUSEEVENTF_ABSOLUTE | MOUSEEVENTF_VIRTUALDESK flags and the absolute coordinates relative to the entire virtual desktop.

However, with my current code, the mouse input gets wrongly positioned.
I am confused on how to correctly calculate the absolute coordinates.

At the moment, I do retrieve the absolute coordinates using the formula discussed on [another question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12870535/moving-mouse-in-c-sharp-coordinate-units).
To get the width/height of the virtual screen, I use [GetSystemMetrics](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-getsystemmetrics) with SM_CXVIRTUALSCREEN/SM_CYVIRTUALSCREEN parameter.

```
// ________________________________________________
//
// GetAbsoluteCoordinate
//
// PURPOSE: 
// Convert pixel coordinate to absolute coordinate (0-65535).
//
// RETURN VALUE:
// Absolute Coordinate
// ________________________________________________
//
UINT16 GetAbsoluteCoordinate(INT PixelCoordinate, INT ScreenResolution)
{
    UINT16 AbsoluteCoordinate = ( (65536 * PixelCoordinate) / ScreenResolution ) + 1;
    return AbsoluteCoordinate;
}


// ________________________________________________
//
// GetAbsoluteCoordinates
//
// PURPOSE: 
// Retrieve virtual screen absolute coordinates from pixel coordinates.
//
// PARAMETERS:
// x, y coordinates passed by reference. These will be changed by the function and used as return values.
//
// RETURN VALUE:
// None (see parameters)
// ________________________________________________
//
void GetAbsoluteCoordinates(INT32 &X, INT32 &Y)
{
    // Get multi-screen coordinates
    MONITORINFO MonitorInfo = { 0 };
    MonitorInfo.cbSize = sizeof(MonitorInfo);
    if (GetMonitorInfoW(hMonitor, &MonitorInfo))
    {
        // 1) Get pixel coordinates of topleft pixel of target screen, relative to the virtual desktop ( coordinates should be 0,0 on Main screen);
        // 2) Get pixel coordinates of mouse cursor, relative to the target screen;
        // 3) Sum topleft margin pixel coordinates with mouse cursor coordinates;
        X = MonitorInfo.rcMonitor.left + X;
        Y = MonitorInfo.rcMonitor.top + Y;

        // 4) Transform the resulting pixel coordinates into absolute coordinates.
        X = GetAbsoluteCoordinate(X, GetSystemMetrics(SM_CXVIRTUALSCREEN));
        Y = GetAbsoluteCoordinate(Y, GetSystemMetrics(SM_CYVIRTUALSCREEN));
    }
} 



// ________________________________________________
//
// SendMouseInput
//
// PURPOSE: 
// Send mouse input, supporting any of the connected displays
//
// PARAMETERS:
// X, Y are pixel coordinates, relative to the current screen.
// ________________________________________________
//
 void SendMouseInput(INT X, INT Y) 
  {
     INPUT Input;
     GetAbsoluteCoordinates(X, Y);
     memset(&Input, 0, sizeof(INPUT)); 
     Input.type = INPUT_MOUSE;
     Input.mi.dx = X;
     Input.mi.dy = Y;
     Input.mi.dwFlags = MOUSEEVENTF_ABSOLUTE | MOUSEEVENTF_VIRTUALDESK | MOUSEEVENTF_MOVE | MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTDOWN;
     SendInput(1, &Input, sizeof(Input));
  }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> 3. Get the pixel coordinates relative to the whole virtual screen: to do
>    this, we sum the coordinates of the current screen margin (topleft
>    pixel) with the coordinates of the point to click;

It looks like you are using the coordinates(`X,Y`) relative to the monitor. How did you get the coordinates?

If so, then the sample is basically no problem. If your mouse coordinates are obtained by something similar to `GetCursorPos`, then you do not need to calculate the coordinates relative to the virtual screen (it is).

The sample almost work for me, I've changed some code as below:

```
#include <windows.h>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
// ________________________________________________
//
// GetAbsoluteCoordinate
//
// PURPOSE: 
// Convert pixel coordinate to absolute coordinate (0-65535).
//
// RETURN VALUE:
// Absolute Coordinate
// ________________________________________________
//
INT GetAbsoluteCoordinate(INT PixelCoordinate, INT ScreenResolution)
{
    INT AbsoluteCoordinate = MulDiv(PixelCoordinate, 65535, ScreenResolution);
    return AbsoluteCoordinate;
}

void GetAbsoluteCoordinates(HMONITOR hMonitor, INT32& X, INT32& Y)
{
    // Get multi-screen coordinates
    MONITORINFO MonitorInfo = { 0 };
    MonitorInfo.cbSize = sizeof(MonitorInfo);
    if (GetMonitorInfoW(hMonitor, &MonitorInfo))
    {
        // 1) Get pixel coordinates of topleft pixel of target screen, relative to the virtual desktop ( coordinates should be 0,0 on Main screen);
        // 2) Get pixel coordinates of mouse cursor, relative to the target screen;
        // 3) Sum topleft margin pixel coordinates with mouse cursor coordinates;
        X = MonitorInfo.rcMonitor.left + X;
        Y = MonitorInfo.rcMonitor.top + Y;

        // 4) Transform the resulting pixel coordinates into absolute coordinates.
        X = GetAbsoluteCoordinate(X, GetSystemMetrics(SM_CXVIRTUALSCREEN));
        Y = GetAbsoluteCoordinate(Y, GetSystemMetrics(SM_CYVIRTUALSCREEN));
    }
}

void SendMouseInput(HMONITOR hMonitor, INT X, INT Y)
{
    INPUT Input[2];
    GetAbsoluteCoordinates(hMonitor, X, Y);
    memset(Input, 0, sizeof(INPUT));
    Input[0].type = Input[1].type = INPUT_MOUSE;
    Input[0].mi.dx = Input[1].mi.dx = X;
    Input[0].mi.dy = Input[1].mi.dy = Y;
    Input[0].mi.dwFlags = MOUSEEVENTF_ABSOLUTE | MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTDOWN | MOUSEEVENTF_MOVE | MOUSEEVENTF_VIRTUALDESK;
    Input[1].mi.dwFlags = MOUSEEVENTF_ABSOLUTE | MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTUP | MOUSEEVENTF_MOVE | MOUSEEVENTF_VIRTUALDESK;

    SendInput(2, Input, sizeof(INPUT));
}
BOOL CALLBACK Monitorenumproc(
    HMONITOR Arg1,
    HDC Arg2,
    LPRECT Arg3,
    LPARAM Arg4)
{
    SendMouseInput(Arg1, 725, 85);
    return TRUE;
}
int main(void)
{
    EnumDisplayMonitors(NULL,NULL, Monitorenumproc,0);
    return 0;
}
```

Result:

I have 2 monitors with the same display resolution(1920 x 1080) to test like:
[image]

The sample will click at the same place on each monitor.

Further reading: [The Virtual Screen](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/gdi/the-virtual-screen)

Comment: The error was indeed in how I was getting the pixel coordinates, before converting them.
Thank you for your code sample, it helped to clear things up.