# SendInput Coordinates Confusion

Tags: c++, winapi

I am trying to understand how SendInput() works with mouse input. As an example, I have a dual monitor display. My 2160p monitor is "above" the 1440p primary monitor. I am trying to send mouse input to the bottom right corner of the above 2160 monitor. Unfortunately, the cursor just ends up in the bottom right corner of my 1440p primary monitor instead.

I know that the top left corner of my primary monitor is (0,0), and the bottom right is (2560,1440). From what I understand, all coordinates are in relation to the primary monitor. So shouldn't I just be able to subtract the resolution of the above monitor from the primary one to move to the exact same location on the above?

I have tried both adding and subtracting, but I keep ending up in the bottom corner of the primary monitor.

```
INPUT input;

input.type = INPUT_MOUSE;
input.mi.dx = (2560 - 3840) * (65536.f / (float)GetSystemMetrics(SM_CXSCREEN));
input.mi.dy = (1440 - 2160) * (65536.f / (float)GetSystemMetrics(SM_CYSCREEN));
input.mi.dwFlags = MOUSEEVENTF_ABSOLUTE | MOUSEEVENTF_MOVE;
input.mi.mouseData = 0;
input.mi.dwExtraInfo = NULL;
input.mi.time = 0;

SendInput(1, &input, sizeof(INPUT));
```

UPDATE: Here is one of my failed attempts using the RECT structure from GetMonitorInfo. I am probably making some sort of obvious mistake, but I can't figure it out.

```
DXGI_OUTPUT_DESC output_desc;

output->GetDesc(&output_desc);

MONITORINFOEX info;
info.cbSize = sizeof(info);
GetMonitorInfo(output_desc.Monitor, (LPMONITORINFO)&info);

INPUT input;

input.type = INPUT_MOUSE;
input.mi.dx = (info.rcMonitor.right) * (65536.f / (float)GetSystemMetrics(SM_CXVIRTUALSCREEN));
input.mi.dy = (info.rcMonitor.top) * (65536.f / (float)GetSystemMetrics(SM_CYVIRTUALSCREEN));
input.mi.dwFlags = MOUSEEVENTF_ABSOLUTE | MOUSEEVENTF_VIRTUALDESK| MOUSEEVENTF_MOVE;
input.mi.mouseData = 0;
input.mi.dwExtraInfo = NULL;
input.mi.time = 0;

SendInput(1, &input, sizeof(INPUT));
```

[image]

Comment: Have you tried using `SetCursorPos`?  (Although this is constrained by `ClipCursor`).

Comment: try using relative coordinates by not using MOUSEEVENTF_ABSOLUTE. Just a guess that absolute coordinates might not work across multiple monitors.

Comment: Use `GetMonitorInfo()` to get the rectangle of the desired monitor within the virtual screen, and then send the mouse cursor to the desired coordinates within that rectangle.

Comment: @RemyLebeau Would you be able to post an example as an answer? I had tried something similar earlier with the RECT, but I probably made an error on the calculation.

Comment: @MemeMachine it would be better if you showed what you tried, then someone can explain why it didn't work.

Comment: @RemyLebeau I added it to the original post. I'm getting the cursor in the top left of primary monitor

Comment: @MemeMachine the monitor's rectangle is in absolute coordinates in the virtual desktop. Since you want the bottom-right corner of the rectangle, I would suggest adding the `MOUSEEVENTF_VIRTUALDESK` flag and then move the cursor to coordinates `info.rcMonitor.right, info.rcMonitor.bottom`, normalized against `SM_C(X|Y)VIRTUALSCREEN` instead of `SM_C(X|Y)SCREEN`

Comment: Related/dupe: [Calculate normalized coordinates for SendInput() in a multi-monitor environment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62759122/)

Comment: @RemyLebeau I tried that as well using bottom, top, etc. I'm still not able to get the mouse on the other monitor. I added some information from the debugger that could help with the problem

Comment: @MemeMachine Is it normal if the monitors are set to the same resolution? I suggest you could try to [set the default DPI awareness](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/hidpi/setting-the-default-dpi-awareness-for-a-process)